# How to change short user id in AWS S3 "Create bucket" dialog

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an old Amazon account that I'm now using as the root account for AWS. When I go to create my very first S3 bucket, on the 3rd screen ("Set Permissions"), under "User ID" is a name next to the parenthetical "(Owner)". The name there is wrong.

Presumably, the name refers to my account. It's a company name I used long ago, and might have one day been an identifier of some kind associated with my Amazon account, but I haven't used the name in over 10 years, and I can't figure out how to change it. I would like to change that name.

It is not my email address. It is not my account number or canonical AWS user ID. It is not my "Account Name" nor does that name appear anywhere that I can find under "My Account". There are no IAM Users, Groups, or Roles configured.

Where can I go to change the name that appears on this dialog?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SF Francis. What problem is this causing? Is it just a cosmetic issue? In my account that's the first part of the email address of the root account owner. You may have to [transfer your root account to another owner](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/).

Comment: Cosmetic, unless it's an indication that some email address I no longer control has permissions of some kind on this account. This name is part of a domain name that I no longer own. Thanks for the tip; I'll follow up with AWS support.

Comment: Unless you pay for support I doubt they'll help much. Have a look in IAM, and try to work out the root account. You can have the root account email changed by AWS, but AWS will ask you plenty of questions to validate you're the real owner - as they should.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32680956/1695906

Comment: The AWS Developer Forum does show the old name, and I can update it there. But S3 still shows the old name when I create a new bucket. This appears to be a bug in S3.